Convert multiple rows of tuples into Dataframe in python
I have a series of tuple (looks like below) which are generated as the output of a particular step in my python program. This value is stored in a variable called out_put and print(out_put) shows the below result exactly.
('20240510', 'female', '21', '15')
('20240510', 'male', '118', '96')
I want to convert this into a Dataframe, so that I can load into a table (bigquery). The dataframe should like
index    Date_YYYYMMDD    Gender    Sessions    User
0        20240510         female    21          15
1        20240510         male      118         96

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
I have tried
print('List')
lst = list(out_put)  
print(lst)

print('Dataframe')
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)  

It is only fetching the last row from the result and transposing the row.

You'd better use the data structure list instead of a tuple.
Try the code below:
import pandas as pd
 
data = {'Date_YYYYMMDD': [20240510, 20240510],
        'Gender': ['female', 'male'],
        'Sessions': [21, 118],
        'User': [15, 96]}
 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)


Two minor nitpicks, if I may: 1. If you're going to say something like "You'd better...", you should back it up with why it's better; 2. What you've referred to as a "data structure list" here is typically called a "dictionary". That said, this answer does work (though OP would have to restructure the function that generates the output they're getting).

The output which I have is being generated in form of tuple. I cannot use data structure.

You just need to collect the out_put data into a list, then you can convert that list directly into a DataFrame with the desired column names
import pandas as pd


# collect your tuples into a list
data = [
    ('20240510', 'female', '21', '15'),
    ('20240510', 'male', '118', '96'),
]

# create DataFrame using data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=['Date_YYYYMMDD', 'Gender', 'Sessions', 'User'],
)

print(df)  # here's the result
#   Date_YYYYMMDD  Gender Sessions User
# 0      20240510  female       21   15
# 1      20240510    male      118   96

